# Tumblr share url

Tags: share, tumblr

I've came across this page https://www.tumblr.com/examples/share/sharing-links-to-articles.html which shows a possible way to customly create a share URL for tumblr.

Simplified version of what they have:

```
<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com" target="blank_">Click to share</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m5ow6bhs/2/

This will take you to the log in page or straight to the share page if you're already logged in. However, if you change the `http%3A%2F%2F` part to a simple `http://` it will now load to a "Not Found Page". http://jsfiddle.net/m5ow6bhs/3/ What the hell Tumblr?

Do you guys have any idea what's going on or what's the correct code to share something to Tumblr?

Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with most share services, the `URL` should be passed as an encoded string. This supports the OPs comments about `http%3A%2F%2F`(encoded) and `http://` (raw).

Tumblr provides variable transformations in the theme operators to handle encoding, but sadly it doesn't work with custom variables.

One quick solution is to drop the `http://` part. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L9jd8dhz/

Comment: Perhaps using php's `urlencode('something')` ? http://viper-7.com/aPtsFr Though I'm using it along with Wordpress and what outputs the url is `<?php the_permalink(); ?>`. Tried implementing like `<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=<?php urlencode( the_permalink() ) ?>">` but isn't working... Any clues?

Comment: I believe you missed `echo`, `<?php echo urlencode('http://google.com') ?>`. Example: http://viper-7.com/glkrIZ

Comment: Yep. Still not working with the wordpress' permalink though. Any ideas?

Comment: Saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274157/wordpress-php-url-encoding-issue and used get_permalink instead of the_permalink it now works :)

Comment: Ahh, yep makes sense. `the_permalink()` includes the echo! :D

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered as of recently that the share URL needs to be updated as such:

`https://www.tumblr.com/widgets/share/tool?shareSource=legacy&canonicalUrl=<-urlencode(share_url)->&posttype=link`

The `&posttype=` seems to be a new requirement to make the share work correctly.

Comment: I neutralized the downvote you received, because I found that you are sort of right. When the `posttype` parameter is not given, Tumblr seems to search for images, which takes a long time.